# how to make responsive multi dimension grid same height in two colum

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have layout similar to one show in below image, If images are same height then layout is fine but the moment image is of different dimension design breaks.

[image]

Design has two main columns with 50% width, First blog items takes 50% space and other 4 blog items use other 50% space in which i show other items.

can i make it same height so that all images fit without breaking design.

If i try one thing other thing break initially i had tried this using flex box both that had some issues so i moved to grids and now i face different issue her.  I have no control over image as they will be of different dimension

Code pen example https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/xxPWxKj

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column1 columnX grid-col" style="background-color:#f00;">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x324/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
 
    <div class=" column2 column grid-col" style="background-color:#f00;">
      <div class="row margin-0">
        <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#aaa;">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x324/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
          <h2>Column 2</h2>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#bbb;">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
          <h2>Column 3</h2>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row margin-0">
        <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#ccc;">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x400/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
          <h2>Column 4</h2>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#ddd;">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
          <h2>Column 5</h2>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks as though you are trying to create a grid. I suggest scrapping positioning with float and investigate CSS grid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.column1 {
  grid-area: column1;
}

.column2 {
  grid-area: column2;
}

.column3 {
  grid-area: column3;
}

.column4 {
  grid-area: column4;
}

.column5 {
  grid-area: column5;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'column1 column1 column2 column3' 'column1 column1 column2 column3'
  'column1 column1 column4 column5'
  'auto auto column4 column5';
}

.row div {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1 columnX grid-col" style="background-color:#f00;">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column2 grid-col" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column3 grid-col" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column4 grid-col" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column5 grid-col" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the same layout as show in image

Comment: @Learning You want each image to fill the entire div? or want the image to be as background?

Comment: Either way.. my object is that design should not break